# How to remove a vehicle from firebase database when it is no longer visible in the gps

Tags: android, firebase

I made an Android app for controlling vehicles through **Firebase**. Everything is working well, except when a vehicle is no longer on GPS, even when I turn off the device, it still shows on the map like it still exist.

How can I know that a car is no longer exists?

Comment: some code please mate :)

Comment: Without seeing code it's impossible to be sure. But it's likely to involved using [`onDisconnect()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/offline-capabilities.html#section-presence)

Comment: OK. Thank you. I used the SFVehicles demo and there is no onDiconncect on their demo. I will try to search pn the web foe onDisconnect. Thanks

Comment: I used the following code, but when I turn off the user's application , the user is still on the map and not sending on onDestroy:

Comment: Firebase presenceRef = new Firebase(GEO_FIRE_REF+"disconnectmessage");
// Write a string when this client loses connection
        presenceRef.onDisconnect().removeValue(new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(FirebaseError error, Firebase firebase) {
                if (error != null) {
                    System.out.println("could not establish onDisconnect event:" + error.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });